# Кликабельные ссылки под изображением

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть меню с различными ссылками. При размещении поверх него полупрозрачного изображения, пункты меню становятся некликабельны. Подскажите, есть ли способ сделать их активными при том, что изображение останется сверху?

Comment: Добавьте код к вашему вопросу

Answer (score 1):

Ответ нашел сам: в CSS-свойствах верхнего изображения прописать `pointer-events: none;`

Таким образом, изображение станет "прозрачным" для действий курсором мыши и кнопки под ним станут кликабельными.

Answer (score 0):

они у тя снизу просто остались, то что должно быть скикабельным, добавь ему

```
z-index: 1000;
```

и добавь ему тоже слой полупрозрачный  и сделай его кликабельным

Comment: и перед эти position:relative;

Comment: Такой вариант не подходит, т.к. относительно главного (основного) фона, ссылки потеряют цвет и станут менее читаемы. Сам нашел ответ: изображению верхнему добавить `pointer-events: none;`

Comment: надо просто подобрать цвет, это легче, чем строить костыли...

Comment: не написал о цветах, зная, просто подумал что сообразил бы уж...  легче подобрать цвет...

Answer (score 0):

Привет =)
Для решения этой проблемы вам понадобится псевдоэлемент **::before**.

```css
.menu{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  position: relative;
}

.menu::before{
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.menu a{
  margin-right: 8px;
  color: black;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu a:hover{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>
</div>
```